# Передача ссылки с мобильного браузера в моё прилоежние, без запуска приложения

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-intent, share, link

С помощью опции "поделиться" в мобильном браузере передаю ссылку открытого сайта в приложение, где с помощью:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

получаю адрес ссылки, но в следствии запускается моё приложение. Каким образом сделать так, чтобы оно возможно в фоновом режиме или другим образом получило данную ссылку без явного запуска приложения.

Я использую такие интент фильтры:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Есть изобретательский приём "сделать чуть меньше требуемого": здесь его можно приложить, разрешив запуск, но после обработки данных немедленно выйдя.

Comment: А не странно ли будет выглядеть - юзер нажал "поделиться", выбрал Ваше приложение и... тишина!?